# How to get number of elements in file?

Tags: c, command-line, args

Right now, I have

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Invalid number of command line parameters, exiting...\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int *numReadings;
    load_readings(argv[1], numReadings);

    return 0;
}

    int *load_readings(char fileName[], int *numReadings) {
        FILE *in = NULL;
        in = fopen(fileName, "r");

        if (in == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to open a file named \"%s\", exiting...\n", fileName);
            fclose(in);
            exit(4);
        }

        printf("%s\n", fileName);
        int size = atoi(fileName);
        printf("Size is %d\n", size);
        int *data = (int *) calloc(size, sizeof(int));

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
            fscanf(in, "%d", (data + i));
        }
    }
```

And When I do size = atoi(fileName) it returns 0. On multiple sites including this one, I've seen people do "atoi(argv[1])" but mine constantly returns 0. My sample.txt file has a bunch of 3-digit numbers separated by spaces. I am under the impression that once I get the size correctly, everything else below it will work.

Comment: I think you're confused about what `atoi` does - it just converts an integer represented as a string to an actual integer. So unless your filename is something like "12345" it's not going to do much.

Comment: See the [`stat`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/stat.html) function.

Comment: another way to get the "number of elements in a file" : `wc fileName`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`atoi` does not tells `size`, it just converts `string` into `integer`.
 for knowing `size` of file you need to seek to the end of the file and then ask for the position:

```
    fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END); // seek to end of file
    size = ftell(fp);    //get current file pointer
   fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET); // seek back to beginning of file
```

Comment: I ended up using this and then dividing ftell(fp) by 4. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `atoi(string_value)` returns number only if the `string_value` can be converted to an integer, for example `int size = atoi("1");`, the value of `size` will be `1`. But if `int size = atoi("asd");`, the value will be `0`, because `asd` cannot be converted to an integer

If you want to get file's size, you can use `struct stat`.

Comment: I don't believe I want 'stat', as I want the number of elements in the file.(For example, my file has 48 three-digit numbers), but I won't always know it's 48.

Comment: @user1799147 If you have the total size of the file, and the size of each element in the file, it's easy to calculate the number of elements.

Comment: I see, you can try `fseek` and `ftell` functions.

Answer (score 0):

`atoi()` converts a string to integer, it seems like you want to know the file size, or specifically, how many numbers the file has to allocate memory, if the data looks exactly like `123 123 123...` 3-digit numbers separated by spaces, then using `stat()` which returns the size of the file in bytes you can just divide by 4:

```
struct stat st;
/* find the file size in bytes */
/* should check for errors */
fstat(fileName, &st);

/* divide the number of bytes by 4 to get the number of numbers */
int size = st.st_size / 4; 

/* just in case the last number doesn't have a space */
size += (st.st_size % 4) != 0; 

/* allocate memory  */
int *data = calloc(size, sizeof(int));
```

Note: I don't really like this solution, you should allocate an initial buffer say 100 integers and if you need more you should use  `realloc()`